# Do emails contain an out off office flag that can be read from PHP

Tags: php, email, outlook

I'm making some improvements to an internal ticketing system.  The system pulls emails from our exchange server and converts them into tickets in the system.  We already take information from the header of each email during this process of ticket generation.

What I would like to know is if there is a way to know for certain if an email is an out-of-office reply and has been automatically sent back.  This would be from any system and not just Outlook.  This would be useful as these emails could be filtered out and not converted into tickets, reducing spam in our system and saving our agents time.

However this really has to be spot on as we would rather handle these emails manually than miss an email that wasn't automated.  Another helpful thing to detect would be bounce backs from invalid addresses, server messages and the like.

I am developing in PHP but any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to guess no; there is very little standardized re: email content (once you get past encodings and MIME types)

Comment: Well, if you are using an exchange server, you can try and make sure that the emails sent are always `text/html` while the out-of-office ones are `text/plain`. Other then that, nothing much you can do...

Comment: I wouldn't risk, take the effort of handle these emails manually !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is discussed in RFC 3834 [Recommendations for Automatic Responses to Electronic Mail](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3834). It defines the `Auto-Submitted`  header field that indicates if the message was sent automatically. Check if it's there and if it is, then exclude that message.

Comment: I would go with this answer :)

Comment: Thanks Marcus, the aim of this question was really just to find out information as I didn't expect a perfect solution.  This looks like something that I can safely implement and it should become more and more effective over time.  I wasn't so foolish to suggest that I could solve this problem, only look into the issue and see what was possible so this seems like a good result!

Answer (score 1):

I summarized what I have found on stackoverflow about this topic.
Following code is a function that checks the subject and header returned by imap_fetchheader or imap_headerinfo.

If only every email client would do the same :-| Usually they should send an empty return-path, that can be identified by your script to filter an automatic reply. However, in my tests showed that this header were not send by the Outlook versions I have used.

The identifier strings are stored in an array to make it easier to adjust to your needs.

```
 /**
 * Function _MailIsAutoSubmitted
 * @return true|false
 * @category Mail
 * @author this->guy
 */
function _MailIsAutoSubmitted($Mailbox,$EmailID){
    $Found = false;

    //Check Headers
    $Header = imap_fetchheader($Mailbox,$EmailID);
    $HeaderIdentifiers = array(
        '([X-]{0,2})Auto-Response-Suppress:([\s]*)([All|OOF])',
        'Auto-Submitted:([\s]*)auto-([replied|notified|generated])',
        'X-MS-Exchange-Inbox-Rules-Loop:',
        'X-Autorespond',
        '([X-]{0,2})Precedence:([\s]*)([auto_reply|bulk|junk])'
    );
    for($x=0;$x<count($HeaderIdentifiers);$x++){
        if(preg_match('/'.$HeaderIdentifiers[$x].'/is',$Header)){
            $Found = true;
        }
    }

    //Check Subject
    $Subject = trim(imap_headerinfo($Mailbox,$EmailID)->subject);
    $SubjectIdentifiers = array(
        'Auto:',
        'Automatic Reply:',
        'Auto Response:'
    );
    for($x=0;$x<count($SubjectIdentifiers);$x++){
        if(preg_match('/^'.$SubjectIdentifiers[$x].'/is',$Subject)){
            $Found = true;
        }
    }
    return $Found;
}
```

Comment: X-Auto-Response-Suppress should not be used here, it's used for **outgoing** e-mails which you don't want an autoreply to...

Answer (score 0):

Aside from reading the actual text of the email and looking for patterns with regex, you might want to take a look at the email headers and see if there are any particular headers that are set in any of these circumstances.  I'm having a hard time understanding how you would have to deal with bounce messages when your address book comes out of exchange.